# What is the meaning and definition of "-scape"?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

The words **"landscape", "seascape", "cityscape", "spacescape", "sandscape", "skyscape"** and many more at [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-scape) have a common **-scape suffix**.

> I've found in the [Online Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scape) that
> **-scape suffix** means: *used to form nouns referring to a wide view of a place, often one represented in a picture*

Is it the only meaning and definition?

Comment: If there were other meanings, I expect that Cambridge would give them. The etymology of [*landscape*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=landscape) is interesting.

Comment: All the words in [SCOWL](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) that end in *-scape*: [hastebin.com/raw/uvozupecet](http://hastebin.com/raw/uvozupecet).

Comment: @user2684291 What has "escape" in common with -scape? And never heard of the word "ascape" before, dics say it doesn't exist.

Comment: I didn't say it has – maybe the other words can help you (i.e., you could look up their definitions and determine whether your assumption holds). I've also never heard of that word, but it exists, I assure you, as the OED does have an entry for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*-scape* is not a native English suffix. It arises by extension from the term *landscape*, meaning a painting of a rural or remote area; this was taken into English in the 17th century from Dutch *landschap*, at a period when the Netherlands were perhaps the major center of artistic innovation in Europe.

- This is a narrow, specialized sense of Dutch *landschap*, which generally means "region" and is composed of *land*, pretty much the same as the English cognate with the same spelling, and *-schap*, a suffix cognate with English *-ship* having the general sense "state, condition".

In English, however, all senses of *-scape* are extended from the art sense, sometimes literally (*seascape*, for instance) and sometimes figuratively (*mindscape*, *soundscape*).

Comment: I doubt the others are either...

Answer (score 0):

**-scape** = a broad view of e.g. a scene.

This gives rise to the name for the orientation of paper when printing
= land-scape versus portrait.

Answer (score 0):

**-SCAPE**
used to form nouns referring to a wide view of a place, often one represented in a picture:

landscape

seascape

cityscape

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scape

Comment: This adds nothing to the accepted answer.